# Adding background color for full screen containing List/Tableview in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I wanted to change background color of the whole screen(including safe area) in SwiftUI.

Adding following code to outermost view works for all the views except if given view contains `List`

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(Color.red)
```

I wanted to add background color for the full screen containing List. I have tried multiple things like,

Adding `ZStack` with first element as `Color.red`, but not worked

`Color.red` with `List` as an overlay, but it still not worked.

Only thing working for me is converting `List` to `ScrollView`, but that I don't want.

Do anyone have any other solution to make that work, or Apple doesn't provide anyway to change background color for `List`?(should support atleast from iOS14 to latest)

Comment: You can’t until the next Xcode and iOS. You would have to make your own list using the other views such as a VStack

Comment: Yeah right. What I have found after starting swiftUI is, they made simple things complex and complex things to simple.

Comment: They are just trying to make coding more accessible. SwiftUI provides basic building blocks, it may slowly get to be as capable as UIKit but it is like using mega blocks instead of Lego’s.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Xcode 14b4 - new beta, new fun.**

There is new modifier on Xcode 14 for that (Xcode 14b4):

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("Item 1")
        Text("Item 2")
        Text("Item 3")
    }
    //.scrollContentBackground(Color.blue) // << absent now !!
    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) // Xcode 14b4+
    .background(Color.blue) // << also this needed !!
}
```

Comment: I know about this(I have already searched enough), but this is not backward compatible and still in beta. What to do for our current implementations? thats why I mentioned that, it must be iOS 14+ compatible.

Comment: @MehulThakkar Did you solve that? Got the same issue

Comment: @Tometoyou I haven't find proper solution yet, but the workaround is to use `ScrollView` instead of using `List` in this case. In swiftui both scrollview and list works almost similar except some inbuilt padding and rowseparator etc. lazyloading portion is handled by `ForEach`, so you can use scrollView when required instead of going for List.